# Creating polygons from a list of lat long in R

Tags: r, dataframe, geospatial, polygon

I have a list with more than 500k of lines containing Id, lat and long like below:

```
Id  Latitude    Longitude   
1   7896    -50.33766   -22.23764   
2   7896    -50.33768   -22.23767   
3   7896    -50.33768   -22.23768   
4   7896    -50.33770   -22.23775
```

I need to create a polygon geometry according Id, each one making a different polygon.

How can I create a SpatialPolygonDataFrame with this data?

Can someone help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that you have several unique values in the `Id` column of your data, you could apply a function to each of these to create a list of `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame`. Then, you can `rbind` the list using `do.call`. But, this should work also with one unique Id.

```
library(sp)

# recreating your data

data = structure(list(Id = c(7896, 7896, 7896, 7896), 
                      Latitude = c(-50.33766, -50.33768, -50.33768, -50.3377),
                      Longitude = c(-22.23764, -22.23767, -22.23768, -22.23775)), 
                 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

# Applying a function to each unique value in the Id column of data

poly_list <- sapply(unique(data$Id), function(x){
  # create a polygon for each unique Id
  poly = Polygon(data[data$Id == x, 3:2]) # or Polygon(data[data$Id == x, c('Longitude', 'Latitude')])
  # create a spatial polygon from the polygon
  polys = SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(poly), ID = x)))
  # convert the spatial polygons to spatial polygons dataframe
  as(polys, 'SpatialPolygonsDataFrame')
})

# rbind the list of spatial polygons dataframe

poly_list <- do.call(rbind, poly_list)

# visualize 

plot(poly_list)
```